Sign In With Github Flutter
I am trying to implement sign in with github functionality, but the broswser stop on this screen and isn't redirect back to the app.

here is code
Future<void> signInWithGitHub() async {
    final clientId = 'my client id';
    // final redirectUri =
    //     'http://localhost:8000/auth/callback'; // Same as in GitHub settings
    final redirectUri = 'telegrammy://auth';

    final url = Uri.https('github.com', '/login/oauth/authorize', {
      'client_id': clientId,
      'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
      'scope': 'read:user user:email',
    });
    print(url.toString());
    // Open the GitHub login page
    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
        url: url.toString(), callbackUrlScheme: "telegrammy");

    // Extract the code from the result
    final code = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['code'];
    if (code != null) {
      // Exchange code for an access token
      final accessToken = await getAccessToken(code);
      if (accessToken != null) {
        // Use accessToken to fetch user details
        final userData = await getGitHubUser(accessToken);
        print("User Info: $userData");
      }
    }
  }

i am make sure that the manifest has this filter
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="telegrammy" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>

Also the redirect url is the same as on github which is myapp//:auth, but it still doesn't work.

Why aren't you just using the package:github?  Or any of the OAuth2 packages?

Let users know if you also getting any error on the Debug Console

what package do you suggest as i can't find a good one?
